# How to have sync producer batch messages?

Tags: apache-kafka, clj-kafka

We were using the Kafka 0.8 async producer but it is dropping messages (and there is no aysnc response from another thread or we could keep using async).

We have set the `batch.num.messages` to 500 and our consumer is not changing. I read that `batch.num.messages` only applies to the async producer and not sync so I need to batch myself. We are using `compression.codec=snappy` and our own serializer class.

My question is two-fold:

- Can I assume that I can just use our own serializer class and then send the message on my own?
- Do I need to worry about any special snappy options/parameters that Kafka might be using?

Comment: Did you solve the problem ? Was you hypothesis about asyc producer loosing messages correct ? I am facing similar situation where it looks like the producer is loosing messages very unpredictably. Version being used is `0.8.1.1`. Trying `0.8.2` as well but the I was able to reproduce it. Any batch setting that will lead to not dropping the messages?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's because `batch.num.messages` controls behaviour of **async** producer only. This is explicitly said so in relevant [guide on parameters](https://kafka.apache.org/08/configuration.html):

> The number of messages to send in one batch when using async mode. The producer will wait until either this number of messages are ready to send or queue.buffer.max.ms is reached.

In order to have batching for sync producer you have to send list of messages:

```
public void trySend(List<M> messages) {
    List<KeyedMessage<String, M>> keyedMessages = Lists.newArrayListWithExpectedSize(messages.size());
    for (M m : messages) {
        keyedMessages.add(new KeyedMessage<String, M>(topic, m));
    }
    try {
        producer.send(keyedMessages);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error(ex)
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using `kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer` here.

Once `send` is executed, batch is sent.

> Can I assume that I can just use our own serializer class and then send the message on my own?
>   Do I need to worry about any special snappy options/parameters that Kafka might be using?

Both, compression and serializer are orthogonal features that don't affect batching, but actually applied to individual messages.

Note that there will be api changes and async/sync api will be unified.